# negative feedback op-amp applications

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am asking why there is no limitations or restrictions during cascading more than one op-amp and multiply there gains to get the total gain?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you want to know?

Comment: Yes, please post an example schematic.  Certainly if you try to cascade two op-amps inside of one feedback loop then Bad Things happen.

Answer (score 1):

There are limitations.  Noise for example.  Each stage will multiply the noise of the last stage, which may not allow you to meet your specifications.

Also if your specs require DC coupling, each stage will amplify the offset of the stage before it.  Eventually, you will saturate the output.

There are many other considerations that may limit how many stages you may put in series, but without more specifics it's hard to say what YOUR limitations may be.